# Can I use two SSL certificates on the same hostname for an Azure Web App?

Tags: azure, ssl, https

I want to use two SSL certificates on the same site: www.example.com.

example.com is a Web App hosted with Azure.

If i go to WebApp->All Settings->Custom domains and SSL -> SSL bindings i can upload the two certificates.

I can then bind the first certificate and second certificate on the same Host Name (example.com). It appears to save correctly. However when I navigate away and then come back, only the first certificate has been bound.

I want to do this in order to support ECC and RSA algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be able to get another SSL certificate, but you will only able to install single certificate at the time. SSL can be only issued on Frequently Qualified Domain Name(**FQDN**).

So either you have to remove existing certificate and have to install a new one, but you won’t be able to use both at once. Only **Single SSL certificate** can be bind on the server so it will automatically replace the existing.